No suitable driver found for jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/ and ClassNotFoundException
I'm trying in Java to establish a connection to mysql. When I run my program I get an error that No suitable driver found for jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/bot. I've searched on the internet and found a solution that I need to add Class.forName("com.mysql.cj.jdbc.Driver"); before writing connection = DriverManager.getConnection();.
Said, done. When I run my program now I'll get a new different error.
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.RuntimeException: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: com.mysql.jdbc.Driver
        at net.advancedbots.discordbot.mysql.SQLHandler.connectDatabase(SQLHandler.java:52)
        at net.advancedbots.discordbot.DiscordBotPlugin.main(DiscordBotPlugin.java:24)
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: com.mysql.jdbc.Driver
        at java.base/jdk.internal.loader.BuiltinClassLoader.loadClass(BuiltinClassLoader.java:641)
        at java.base/jdk.internal.loader.ClassLoaders$AppClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoaders.java:188)
        at java.base/java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:525)
        at java.base/java.lang.Class.forName0(Native Method)
        at java.base/java.lang.Class.forName(Class.java:413)
        at java.base/java.lang.Class.forName(Class.java:404)
        at net.advancedbots.discordbot.mysql.SQLHandler.connectDatabase(SQLHandler.java:50)


It's pretty clear to me that the error is a ClassNotFoundException but I don't know how to fix the error. I've tried already the following steps:

adding the connector-java into my pom.xml

<dependency>
    <groupId>mysql</groupId>
    <artifactId>mysql-connector-java</artifactId>
    <version>8.0.33</version>
</dependency>


downloaded manually "Connector/J" went into my project structure -> modules -> dependencies and added the .jar-file into my module-dependencies

So after now a couple of hours I don't know how to fix it. Can anyone help me with this please?

Using Class.forName("com.mysql.cj.jdbc.Driver"); is (relatively) ancient history and should no longer be needed, unless you have very specific/uncommon circumstances. The POM dependency I would expect to see is this one - not what you have (although they may both point to the same JAR).

Now I use your suggestion but it don't work. Same error (without this Class.forName = no suitable driver and with = ClassNotFoundException)

Both errors mean the MySQL JAR file is in the wrong location (it is not on the runtime classpath of your application - and it needs to be). Someone else may know why this is the case, but I don't see enough relevant info in the question to be able to help you. How are you running your app? For example, is it running in a web container such as Tomcat? Maybe you need to add discord as a tag for your question, to get more relevant expertise.

For newer (self-registered) drivers, you could list what is present with java.sql.DriverManager.drivers().forEach(System.out::println);

Do a Maven clean, then rebuild.

Is this a web app?

(A) Create a tiny throwaway app to demonstrate the problem to us. You’ll likely solve your own problem while doing so. (B) Search Stack Overflow to find complete example apps accessing MySQL (and H2 & Postgres) with all necessary JDBC commands, written by me.

@andrewJames Although Class.forName is no longer required, it is still a helpful tool for diagnosing issues. And in this case it makes clear that the driver is not actually on the classpath when the application is run.
